# Preventing visual table interactions/highlights and setting reduced column and row heights with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have found some solutions for the following using c++, but not for python.  I have a table with different set spans that repeats the pattern for the data length.  But I would like all highlights/all visual interactions to be disabled, but still have the table function to allow retrieval of values after click etc (ie not disable the table).  I also cannot minimize the column width of select columns.  It's either zero or the default which is too wide (I'd actually like about 2 to 5px width).  And lastly a similar issue with row heights for selected rows.  With a value of 1 it is reduced, but not to the extent that I would like. If someone could provide a solution that would be great thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem, QStyledItemDelegate, QSizePolicy, QStyle)

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class StyleDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

        #isn't preventing all highlights/visual interactions
        option.state &= ~(QStyle.State_Selected | QStyle.State_MouseOver)

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        # Adjust widths of specific columns can't minimize
        narrow_columns = [6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
        for col in narrow_columns:
            self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(col, 1)  # Either 0, everything else too wide

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget - Example of a cell merge")
        self.resize(660, 300)
        conLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(20)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        # Hide headers
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)


        self.tableWidget.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 20)
        self.tableWidget.setSpan(3, 0, 1, 20)

        data = [('NAME', 'VALUE', 'LPT', 'NLPT', 'SEQ', 'SEQ2', "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7"),
                ('NAME1', 'VALUE1', 'LPT1', 'NLPT1', 'SEQ1', 'SEQ21', "V11", "V21", "V31", "V41", "V51", "V61", "V71")]

        data_offset = 0
        required_rows = len(data) * 4
        total_rows = required_rows

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(total_rows)
        required_rows = len(data) * 4
        for i in range(0, required_rows, 4):

            #Can minimize the row height to some extent, but not below 1
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(i, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setRowHeight(i + 3, 1)

            # Repeat merged cells and data for each data block
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 3, 0, 1, 20)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 0, 0, 1, 20)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 2, 1, 2)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 4, 1, 2)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 7, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 9, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 11, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 13, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 15, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 17, 2, 1)
            self.tableWidget.setSpan(i + 1, 19, 2, 1)


            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 2, QTableWidgetItem(data[data_offset][0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 2, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[data_offset][1])))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][2])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 2, 4, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 2, 5, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 11, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 9, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 7, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 13, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 15, QTableWidgetItem(value))
            try:
                value = str(data[data_offset][3])
            except IndexError:
                value = None
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i + 1, 17, QTableWidgetItem(value))

            data_offset += 1

        # Set properties for the table
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(True)
        self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Apply delegate
        delegate = StyleDelegate()
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForRow(i, delegate)
        self.setLayout(conLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Table()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Setting the option state in the `paint()` (and after having already painted the item) is completely useless. You should do that in `initStyleOption()` instead, after calling the base implementation. Note that you may only ask *one* question per post, and the other aspects you're asking are not related to the first. Besides, I wouldn't suggest using fake rows/columns just to show a thicker border, most importantly because you'll end up with completely inconsistent row and column numbers; a more appropriate implementation of the delegate and the table painting is certainly a much better choice.

Comment: Thanks musicamante.  I have re-worded the question now with reference only to the dotted line around the cells when clicking on it.

Comment: Add `QStyle.State_HasFocus`.

Comment: You're awesome that did it thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest you to take your time and study the QStyle documentation (including *anything* related to styling, including painting and size management).

Comment: Also, please don't edit a question to include answers: that's not how StackOverflow works. If a post is marked as duplicate and that solves your issue, then **do not** edit it providing the solution. This is a Q&A website, answers go in the dedicated section (not in the question). In case the duplication doesn't solve your issue, then explain your reasons in comments (and/or update your post), clarifying the different aspects that don't match the reason of the closure. Please take your time to properly follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).